# How to determine when a user has succesfully logged in using FirebaseUI in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

To log a user in using the firebaseUI library you can do the following:

```swift
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI() 
        guard authUI != nil else {
           return
        }
        authUI?.providers = [
            FUIEmailAuth(), //works
            FUIGoogleAuth(), //works
            FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider() //does not work
        ]
        authUI?.delegate = self
        authUI?.shouldHideCancelButton = true
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
        authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and according to the documentation you include the following function on completion of user log in:

```swift
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth,didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        if let user = authDataResult?.user{
            print("Nice! You've signed in as \(user.uid)")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: K.welcomeSegue, sender: self)
        }
    }
```

However, in my code, when I use the Apple sign-in option this function never runs. Do I need to call this function somewhere? If so how do I call it?

Here is the full code to my view controller:

```swift
class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        if(Auth.auth().currentUser != nil){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.welcomeSegue, sender: self)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        guard authUI != nil else {
           return
        }
        authUI?.providers = [
            FUIEmailAuth(),
            FUIGoogleAuth(),
            FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
        ]
        authUI?.delegate = self
        authUI?.shouldHideCancelButton = true
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
        authViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth,didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        if let user = authDataResult?.user{
            print("Nice! You've signed in as \(user.uid)")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: K.welcomeSegue, sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```